# Adding a custom button to a view with constraints programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I want to programatically add a custom button to a view and also set the constraints for that button. Here is my code:

```
    let button = SummaryButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36))
    button.setTitle("1", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(daysButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    daysView.addSubview(button)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: daysView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: daysView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 36).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 36).isActive = true
```

I don't see the button at all. If I remove the constraints I can see it, but the position is incorrect.

Is there an issue on how I am setting my constraints ? I want to added to the left side of the view.

Comment: First, you're setting both `.leading` and `.centerX` constraints? Second, you have no `Y` position? Should your second line be `.centerY` instead of `X`?

Comment: @DonMag: Ohh...yeah in my mind I wanted to set the Y, not X. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove centerX constraint as you already have leading

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: daysView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

and add top say 50 pts from top of view

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: daysView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50).isActive = true
```